# Setting MINMAXINFO is off by 4px on the X and 5px on the Y

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm handling MINMAXINFO like this:

```
 case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
      {
         LPMINMAXINFO p_info = (LPMINMAXINFO)lParam;
         int total_border_width = 2 * GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME );
         int total_border_height = 2 * GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME ) + 
            GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION ) - GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYBORDER );
         POINT min,max;

         min.x = d->min_w > 0 ? d->min_w + total_border_width : p_info->ptMinTrackSize.x;
         min.y = d->min_h > 0 ? d->min_h + total_border_height : p_info->ptMinTrackSize.y;
         max.x = d->max_w > 0 ? d->max_w + total_border_width : p_info->ptMaxTrackSize.x;
         max.y = d->max_h > 0 ? d->max_h + total_border_height : p_info->ptMaxTrackSize.y;

         p_info->ptMinTrackSize = min;
         p_info->ptMaxTrackSize = max;
        }

       break;
```

And the resolution it sets it to is consistently 4 pixels less than I want on the X, and 5 pixels on the Y. Doing + 4 and + 5 fixes it but that seems like a terrible idea. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I've never really figured out how to do this properly, either.  Instead, I calculate the border size based on the difference between GetWindowRect() and GetClientRect().

Comment: I think you need to look into using `AdjustWindowRect()` to account for the window decorations, but I'm not 100% sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the type of frame you're using. You may need to account for the 3D elements of the border seperately, such as SM_CXEDGE. The client area may have an edge you're not accounting for if it's a 3D client frame.

Answer (score 0):

this is why User32 provides AdjustWindowRect(Ex).

The brief description for AdjustWindowRectEx in MSDN is as follows:

"Calculates the required size of the window rectangle, based on the desired size of the client rectangle. The window rectangle can then be passed to the CreateWindowEx function to create a window whose client area is the desired size."

AdjustWindowRect is the same, but for use with CreateWindow. For MINMAXINFO correction, this should work regardless of which function you used to create the window:

```
RECT rc;
rc.left = 0;
rc.top = 0;
rc.right = desired_width;
rc.bottom = desired_height;
AdjustWindowRectEx(&rc, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE),
     GetMenu(hwnd) != 0, GetWindowLong(GWL_EXSTYLE));
```

rc will be altered to be the dimensions you need for setting the relevant points in MINMAXINFO.